# Cannot open port on Ubuntu

Tags: firewall, minecraft

**What I want:**

Open port 19132 so it is reachable from the LAN.

**What I have:**

My home desktop PC runs Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I have installed Minecraft Bedrock server which serves port 19132/UDP by default. I can configure another port instead, but to no avail: **That port is reported as "closed" even on the same computer.**

I also have an xDSL modem in bridge mode and a router with the port forwarding already set up. I am confident about the port forwarding as other ports are successfully forwarded to other machines on my LAN; this is verified in theory using [yougetsignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and in practise with people outside my LAN.

**What I've already tried:**

1. `sudo ufw status verbose` tells me that ports `19132, 19133, 25565` are open (`ALLOW IN from ANYWHERE`). That should work.
2. I've tried `sudo ufw disable` too but that did not help. I presume a disabled firewall closes all ports?
3. I'm testing the port status with `cat < /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/19132` and `.../udp/...` and the actual LAN IP `.../192.168.1.30/...` but without success.
4. I am also testing with a local LAN computer running Minecraft (Bedrock edition, defaults to UDP 19132) but it also cannot connect to my machine's Minecraft server (which is explicitly set to that port).
5. `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 19132` gives me:
   `udp  0  0.0.0.0:19132  0.0.0.0:*  83312/./bedrock_ser` so it would look like the server is present and listening. It just doesn't hear anything?